# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Hi I have this exception when I try to start spring boot:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextInitializer
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.initialize(SpringApplication.java:262)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:238)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1187)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1176)
        at org.myapp.test.subscription.webservice.Application.main(Application.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 5 more
```

Here is my maven config:

```
<!-- SPRING -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3.redhat-1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
...
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
            </plugin>
...
```

Any ideas why ? Should I add another dependency or do I use a wrong version? Could it be a conflict with another dependency?

Comment: is this all the dependencies being used? Also you are not using the BOM correctly. it should go into dependency mgmt. 

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven-without-a-parent

Highly likely another dependency is overriding some transitive dependencies.

Comment: Indeed that was the issue thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@darren-forsythe indeeed that was the POM configuration :

```
<dependencyManagement>
     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Now it's working thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

its working fine with the above version as well

Answer (score 0):

You asked

> ClassNotFoundException on spring application bootstrapping

The [ClassNotFoundException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html) is a checked exception which occurs when an application tries to load a class through its fully-qualified name and can not find its definition on the classpath, indeed which  occurs mainly when trying to load classes using `Class.forName()`, `ClassLoader.loadClass()`. calls. which in this case happend on bootstraping the [IOC](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) context.

**The [Dependencies(Jar) hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell) is most possible case**

You  may have some transparent dependencies of different version which you need ti exclude or use suitable [plugins](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) to avoid this exception, it also may happens on runtime so best practice is to check version and duplicate transparent dependencies anytime you adding new maven artifact and dependencies in to you `pom.xml` file.

```html
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

So you may not wonder if we remove exclusion and face this exception, schematically, with this mentioned dependencies it will look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BrzI.png).